# JavaScript syntax: bucketing based on days (today, yesterday and past)

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create three buckets of objects. Today, yesterday and past. I am wondering can the following be done in a more concise way in pure JavaScript without any libraries?

```
const [todayBucket, yesterdayBucket] = [0, 1].map(offset =>
  recordings.filter(({ createdOn }) =>
    moment(createdOn).isSame(moment().add(-offset), 'day'),
  ),
);
const pastBucket = recordings.filter(
  recording => ![...todayBucket, ...yesterdayBucket].includes(recording),
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing it without an additional library you could try a custom function that does the same thing

```
function isSame(a,offset) {
    const b = new Date();
    b.setDate(b.getDate() - offset); 
    return a === b
}

const [todayBucket, yesterdayBucket] = [0, 1].map(offset =>
  recordings.filter(({ createdOn }) =>
    isSame(createdOn,offset),
  ),
);
const pastBucket = recordings.filter(
  recording => ![...todayBucket, ...yesterdayBucket].includes(recording),
);
```